# Use node js behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am trying to connect to a Firebase db from behind a corporate proxy.

Getting below error

```
error: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 35.201.97.85:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '35.201.97.85',
  port: 443 }
statusCode: undefined
body: undefined
```

It works perfectly if I connect to my personal hotspot. Any way to make it work on corporate network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proxy inside the .npmrc file

for Windows

```
1. Go to C:/Users/Username
2. Create or find .npmrc file 
3. Add proxy entry inside the file
```

for linux
 Execute following command to find .npmrc file and add the proxy entry inside it. Use following command to list the file:

```
npm config ls -l | grep config
```

or you can try following command:

```
npm config set proxy "http://domain\username:password@servername:port/"
```

or

```
npm config set proxy "http://domain%5Cusername:password@servername:port/"
```

Comment: I do not have a problem with npm. I have already set up a proxy for npm. But I am not able to route to the firebase url. I am getting that error while routing.